# How to get activeElement's role using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to get the active element's role attribute. I can get all the other attributes like `id`, `class`, `title` and so on, as below

```
document.activeElement.title

document.activeElement.class

document.activeElement.tabindex
```

...but I can't get the **role** attribute using **document.activeElement.role**. It throws `undefined`.

How do I get the `role` attribute?

Comment: are you sure the active element has a role property? :)

Comment: `role` is not a native attribute, and you're checking element properties. Non-native attributes are not reflected to the corresponding properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.activeElement.getAttribute('role');
```

Comment: Perfect, it's working as expected. How to trigger an event for this activeElement ?

Comment: You can use dispatchEvent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent